# How to evaluate binary tree (inorder)?

Tags: c

I am trying to evaluate a binary tree (inorder). The result always remains 
the same or giving an unexpected answer. I do not know where the problem is, can 
anyone help me? First I have converted postfix expression to expression tree than evaluate expression tree. I shall be very thankful.

The result is unexpected when I run this program. This the header file.

```
#define POST2EXPTREE_H_INCLUDED
#define MAX 100

struct node
{
    char ch;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
}  *stack[MAX];
typedef struct node node;
void push(node *str);
node *pop();
void convert(char exp[]);
void display(node *temp);

#endif
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include"post2expTree.h"
#define SIZE 100

int top = -1;
void push(node *str)
{
    if (top >= MAX-1)
    printf("Stack is Full ");
    else
    {
        stack[top] = str;
        top++;
    }
}

node *pop()
{
    node *exp;
    if (top < 0)
        printf("Stack is Empty ");
    else
        exp = stack[--top];
    return exp;
}
void convert(char exp[])
{
    node *op1,  *op2;
    node *temp;
    int i;
    for (i=0;exp[i]!='\0';i++)
    if (exp[i] >= 'a'&& exp[i] <= 'z'|| exp[i] >= 'A' && exp[i] <= 'Z' ||isalnum(exp[i]))
    {
        temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp->ch = exp[i];
        temp->right = NULL;
        temp->left = NULL;
        push(temp);
    }
    else if (exp[i] == '+' || exp[i] == '-' || exp[i] == '*' || exp[i] == '/' || exp[i] == '%'
|| exp[i] == '^')
    {
        op1 = pop();
        op2 = pop();
        temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp->ch = exp[i];
        temp->right = op1;
        temp->left = op2;
        push(temp);
    }
}

void display(node *temp)
{
    if (temp != NULL)
    {
        display(temp->left);
        printf("%c", temp->ch);
        display(temp->right);
    }
}
int evaluate(node *temp)
{
    int left,right,value;
    if ((temp->ch) >= 0 || (temp->ch <=9))
    {
        return temp->ch;
    }
    else
    {
        left = evaluate(temp -> left);
        right = evaluate(temp -> right);

        switch(temp->ch)

        {

            case '+':
                value = left + right;
                break;

            case '-':
                 value = left - right;
                 break;


            case '*':
                 value = left * right;
                break;


            case '/':
                 value = left / right;
                break;


            case '%':
                 value = left % right;
                break;


            case '^':
                 value = left ^ right;
                break;


        }
        temp->ch = value;
    }
    return value;

}
```

Comment: Do not scream please. Correct your English. Do not repeat yourself, once is enough. What is your question?

Comment: "The result is unexpected" - what **exactly** does that mean?

Comment: For a novice programmer, it means that the program works out of the box ;)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>     int top = -1;
>     void push(node *str)
>     {
>         if (top >= MAX-1)
>         printf("Stack is Full ");
>         else
>         {
>             stack[top] = str;
>             top++;
>         }
>     }
> ```

- Here `top` is initialized to `-1`, and the very first `push()` wrongly accesses `stack[-1]`; correct that by changing the `else` block to `stack[++top] = str;`.

> ```
>     node *pop()
>     {
>         node *exp;
>         if (top < 0)
>             printf("Stack is Empty ");
>         else
>             exp = stack[--top];
>         return exp;
>     }
> ```

- Here `top` is decremented before accessing the `stack` off by one; correct that by changing the `else` block to `exp = stack[top--];`.

> ```
>     int evaluate(node *temp)
>     {
>         int left,right,value;
>         if ((temp->ch) >= 0 || (temp->ch <=9))
>         {
>             return temp->ch;
> ```

- Here you forgot that you store the operands as single digits `'0'` to `'9'`, not as values `0` to `9`. Correct that by changing to:

  ```
      int left, right, value = temp->ch-'0';
      if (value >= 0 && value <= 9)
      {
          return value;
  ```